# Get first/last row of n-th consecutive group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

What's the easiest way to select a single record/value from the n-th group? The group is determined by a material and it's price(prices can change). I need to find the first date of the last  and the last date of the next to last material-price-groups. So i want to know when exactly a price changed.

I've tried following query to get the first date of the current(last) price which can return the wrong date if that price was used before:

```
DECLARE @material VARCHAR(20)
SET @material = '1271-4303'

SELECT TOP 1 Claim_Submitted_Date 
FROM   tabdata
WHERE Material = @material 
AND Price = (SELECT TOP 1 Price FROM tabdata t2 
             WHERE Material = @material
             ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date DESC)
ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date ASC
```

This also only returns the last, how do i get the previous? So the date when the previous price was used last/first?

I have simplified my schema and created [**this sql-fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3a791/8/0) with sample-data. Here in chronological order. So the  row with ID=7 is what i need since it's has the next-to-last  price with the latest date.

```
ID   CLAIM_SUBMITTED_DATE                   MATERIAL    PRICE
5   December, 04 2013 12:33:00+0000         1271-4303   20
4   December, 03 2013 12:33:00+0000         1271-4303   20   <-- current
3   November, 17 2013 10:13:00+0000         1271-4846   40
7   November, 08 2013 12:16:00+0000         1271-4303   18   <-- last(desired)
2   October, 17 2013 09:13:00+0000          1271-4303   18
1   September, 17 2013 08:13:00+0000        1271-4303   10
8   September, 16 2013 12:15:00+0000        1271-4303   17
6   June, 23 2013 14:22:00+0000             1271-4303   18
9   January, 11 2013 12:22:10+0000          1271-4303   20   <-- a problem since this is older than the desired but will be returned by my simply sub-query approach above
```

Is it even possible to parametrize this value, so the `nthLatestPriceGroup` if i want to know the 3rd last price-date? Note that the query sits in a scalar-valued-function.

**Edit**: Many thanks to all. But unfortunately a  simple `ROW_NUMBER` seems not to help here since i'm trying to get the row with **the most recent price before the current price** for a given material. So `GROUP BY`/`PARTITION BY  material,price` includes rows with the same price that don't belong to the last recent material-price group.

Consider that a price can change from

```
Date             Price     Comment
5 months ago     20        original price, note that this is the same as the curent which causes my query to fail!
3 months ago     18        price has changed, i might need the first and last date
2 months ago     20        price has changed, i might need the first and last date
1 month ago      18        previous price, i need the oldest and newest dates 
NOW              20        current price, i need the first/oldest date from this group
```

So i want the date of the most recent row of the last 20-group, the oldest 20-group is irrelevant. So i must somehow group by **consecutive** prices since a price can repeat after it has already changed.

So actually i only need the most recent `Claim_Submitted_Date` from the price-group that starts with `1 month ago ... previous price` in the list above which is the date until the previous price was valid. The other informations listed in the comments are just nice to have(the `nthLatestPriceGroup` sub-question). That's the row with `ID=7` in the sample data above. By the way, the oldest row of this price-group would be the one with `ID=2`(October, 17) and not `ID=6`(June, 23) even if the latter is older. There was a different price(10) after. That's the reason why i can't use simple ranking functions.

Comment: Just for clarification! what is the result you expect in the sample data you provided in sql-fiddle?

Comment: @huMptyduMpty: Sorry for the confusion, i have edited my answer hopefully with the correct desired row now.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/602d0d/22) Does it solve your query? As far as I understand, you are looking for the `price` based on the `max ID` within the group

Comment: @Kiril: Thanks. But unfortunately it does not return what i need.  I have mistakenly requested the wrong row in the first version of my question. The correct row according to my requirement is the one with `ID=7` and `date=November, 08` (it is commented in my sample data above). That's the correct row because it's first row(date desc) for the last material-price group. The current price is 20 and the last was 18, of the 18-group the most recent is ID=7. You query returns simply the (2nd)oldest for a given material. The main problem is that my groups depend on **consecutive** prices.

Comment: am I right in saying you are looking for 3rd last value for a given MATERIAL ??

Comment: @MuhammedAli: No, i don't know how i can explain it better. Say i have only one material(to simplify it). I'm trying to get the time of all price-changes. So there might be some rows with the current/last price.  I need to know the date when this price was first claimed, that's already solved with my query above. But now i also need to know the last time the previous price was claimed. I have edited my answer. So the main problem is that grouping by price could also include rows which belong to the same price but which is long time ago(there were other prices between for this material).

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The following [SQLFiddleDemo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c2204/6) obtains the desired result and I have tested it with more than 1 material. Basically, the code removes all current groups, checks for past records with different `Price` value and selects the most recent one

Comment: @Kiril: (and others) sql-fiddle seems to be down since yesterday, so i cannot test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use the windowed function ROWNUMBER in a subquery,...

something like this will get you there:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Price ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date DESC) AS Row
```

Here's the update based on your fiddle:

```
DECLARE @material VARCHAR(20)
SET @material = '1271-4303'


SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY Claim_Submitted_Date ASC) AS rn  
FROM tabdata t2 
WHERE Material = @material
) res
WHERE rn=2
```

If idData is incremental(and therefore chronological) you could use this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Material ORDER BY idData DESC) AS rn  
FROM tabdata t2 
WHERE Material = @material
) res
```

Looking at your latest requirements we could all be over thinking it(if I understand you correctly):

```
DECLARE @MATERIAL AS VARCHAR(9)
SET @MATERIAL = '1271-4303'

SELECT  TOP 1 *
FROM tabdata t2 
WHERE Material = @material
AND PRICE <> (  SELECT TOP 1 Price
                FROM tabdata 
                WHERE Material = @material 
                ORDER BY CLAIM_SUBMITTED_DATE desc)
ORDER BY CLAIM_SUBMITTED_DATE desc

--results
idData  Claim_Submitted_Date        Material    Price
7       2013-11-08 12:16:00.000     1271-4303   18
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44512/1) based on this.

Comment: I have tried ranking functions but they didn't give me the result i need. It would be wonderful if you'd use my fiddle to create a working query that returns the first row(ID=1).

Comment: I'll give it a go give me five mins.

Comment: There you go Tim, hope this helps.  Sorry about the SELECT *, I was in a rush.  Go to head off now hope this sorts your issue.

Comment: Check the data on your fiddle, row 1 is differently to your example above.

Comment: Updated fiddle with changes to match the above: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/602d0d/9

Comment: What happens if we have more than 2 records for the same material and price?

Comment: @Mack: Thanks. But unfortunately it does not return what i need.  I have mistakenly requested the wrong row in the first version of my question. The correct row according to my requirement is the one with `ID=7` and `date=November, 08` (it is commented in my sample data above). That's the correct row because it's first row(date desc) for the last material-price group. The current price is 20 and the last was 18, of the 18-group the most recent is ID=7. You query returns simply the (2nd)oldest for a given material. The main problem is that my groups depend on **consecutive** prices.

Comment: @Mack: Your last edit seems to be really the easiest and most efficient approach to get what i actually want. Of course it is very limited, so it doesn't work if i need to know the first instead of the last row of the previous price. Let me have a closer look when i'm back at office(holiday), so that i can accept the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to make it more flexible let us know how and I'm sure we will be able to figure it out.  Have a great holiday!

Comment: @Mack: Thanks, now i'm back in the office and i notice that even my first attempt to get the last(current) price is incorrect, therefore you're last simple approach is it also. I have edited my question accordingly. The problem is that it returns the earliest date the last price was used overall, i need the earliest date the last price was used **since it was used**.

Comment: My approach, while similar to yours is different in two areas.  Yours is PRICE = (subquery) and mine is PRICE <> (subquery), and my outer query is sorted DESC, I have added the results for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Following your last comments, only solution I came with is counting the different price groups according to their `Claim_Submitted_Date`, and then include the obtained group indexes as part as the grouping criteria.
Not sure it will be highly efficient. Hope it will help though.

```
declare @materialId nvarchar(max), @targetrank int
set @materialId = '1271-4303'
set @targetrank =2


;with grouped as (
    select *, 
              (select count( t.price)  -- don't put a DISTINCT here. (I know, I did)
               from tabdata as t 
               where t.Price <> tj.Price 
                 and t.Claim_Submitted_Date> tj.Claim_Submitted_Date 
                  and t.Material= @materialId
              )as group_indicator 
      from tabdata tj 
      where Material= @materialId
), 
rankedClaims as
(
    select grouped.*, row_number() over (PARTITION BY material,price,group_indicator  ORDER BY claim_submitted_date desc) as rank
    from grouped
),
numbered as
(
   select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by Claim_Submitted_Date desc) as RowNumber from
   rankedClaims 
   where rank =1
)
select Id, Claim_Submitted_Date, Material, Price from numbered
    where RowNumber=@targetrank
```

(Not sure also of should two claims on different prices on the same date should be treated `t.Claim_Submitted_Date> tj.Claim_Submitted_Date`)

-------------------- **Previous answer**

Maybe you can try something like :

```
SELECT ranked.[CLAIM_SUBMITTED_DATE]
FROM
(
  SELECT trimmed.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY claim_submitted_date) AS rank FROM
  (
    SELECT a.*
      ,row_number() over (PARTITION BY material,price ORDER BY claim_submitted_date) AS daterank
    FROM tabdata a
    WHERE a.material= '1271-4303'
  )
  AS trimmed
  WHERE daterank=1
) AS ranked
WHERE rank=2
```

Parameterizing the rank seems possible as it is only involved in `WHERE rank=2`

Comment: The same applies here. Sorry for the  initial confusion since my desired result was incorrect. I have edited my answer accordingly. Maybe my ordered sample data above and the comments help to understand what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thx for the follow-up. I had seen  the issue but thought it was not relevant in this case ; and, in fact, parametrizing the rank would not work with any rank greater than 2 (I think I mistranslated "last date of the next to last" ). Will try to have a second look at it

Comment: This seems to work as [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/602d0d/39/0) suggests, thanks. Maybe i will use this approach if i really need to find other price-groups. I have to test it with real data when i'm back at office. The simple last approach of [Mack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20380546/284240) does already what i really need. However, i'll accept this if it really works since it's the luxury-version.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thx, but on second (third?) thought, I'm afraid it's far from luxury and would fail miserably on a simple sequence of two alternating prices... A question much more complex than it first seemed ;-)

Comment: ... and on 4th thought, it just needed to remove a faulty 'distinct' to make it work... done

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DECLARE @material VARCHAR(20), @Nth INT
SET @material = '1271-4303'
SET @Nth = 2

;with CTE1 ([idData],[Claim_Submitted_Date], [Material], [Price], Rn)
as
(
SELECT  *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PRICE DESC) AS rn  
FROM tabdata  
WHERE Material = @material
)
,
CTE2 ([idData],  [Material], [Price], LastDate)
AS(
SELECT [idData],  [Material], [Price], MAX([Claim_Submitted_Date])
FROM CTE1
WHERE rn = @Nth
GROUP BY [idData],  [Material], [Price]
)
SELECT Top 1 [idData],  [Material], [Price], LastDate
FROM CTE2 
ORDER BY LastDate DESC
```

**Result Set**

```
idData  Material    Price   LastDate
  7     1271-4303   18      2013-11-08 12:16:00.000
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately it does not return what i need.  I have mistakenly requested the wrong row in the first version of my question. The correct row according to my requirement is the one with `ID=7` and `date=November, 08` (it is commented in my sample data above). That's the correct row because it's first row(date desc) for the last material-price group. The current price is 20 and the last was 18, of the 18-group the most recent is ID=7. You query returns simply the (2nd)oldest for a given material. The main problem is that my groups depend on **consecutive** prices.

Comment: Thanks, i will have a look at it tomorrow since sql-fiddle is down and i'm at home. If it works i've hoped to find something more consise and efficient since the original query is more complicated and links 10 different tables to find the material, the price and the date and two of these tables contain nearly 100Million rows each.

Comment: I have [tested it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/602d0d/43/0) but it does not return a result row. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried windowed functions such as row_number()

```
 select a.[IDDATA]
, a.[CLAIM_SUBMITTED_DATE]
, a.[MATERIAL]
 , a.[PRICE]
 ,row_number() over (PARTITION by material,price order by claim_submitted_date) as seq
 from tabdata a
 where a.material= '1271-4303'
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/602d0d/1)

Comment: A simple `ROW_NUMBER` seems not to help here since i'm trying to get the row with the most recent price before the current price for a given material. So `GROUP BY`/`PARTITION BY  material,price` include rows with the same price that don't belong to the last recent material-price group. Consider that a price can change from 20(oldest) to 18,back to 20 and then back to 18(newest). I want the date of the most recent row of the last 20-group, the oldest 20-group is irrelevant. So i must somehow group by consecutive prices.