# Find start and end dates from previous episode(s) and the duration of the gap(s) between the episode(s) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have searched around for an answer to this but I have not been able to find one that totally fits my problem.

What I am trying to find are the start and end points for previous 'episodes' and the duration of the gaps between these 'episodes' (if applicable). I have added a link to some example data that I created on SQL Fiddle, which I have tried to replicate the data as best I can.

**What defines an episode?** An episode starts where there is only one open event at a point in time and ends when the last event is closed. Each person can have multiple 'episodes' over a period of time.

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/057e6b)

The table I am reporting from contains parent and child data, not that it is required to identify either parent or child but the data is a little messy, for example there are closed parent records with it's child record(s) still open. There are lots of over lapping dates (sometimes in peculator ways).

I keep getting lost in a maze of statements!!

Any help would be much appreciated!

If any more background information is required just ask!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380290/get-first-last-row-of-n-th-consecutive-group)

Comment: Maybe you must rethink or at least give us more info/details/definitions. I managed to create it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/057e6b/35 but as far I can see at the end it ill degenerate to a single row with the first date and last date. I made some assumptions, like let's work just with root events and ignore not closed ones.

Comment: @jean Your on the right track however I need it grouped by _person_id_. I think I have managed to come up with a solution [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da289/2), however I'm not 100% that it picks up all eventualities (it does work though for the dummy data I have provided).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve the issue myself, I created the following table function that will for each person produce the end date of the previous episode and the start date of the next episode where there was a gap:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun_tbl_find_gaps_in_referrals
(
    @v_person_id int
)
RETURNS 
@gaps TABLE 
(
    end_date smalldatetime,
    start_date smalldatetime
)
AS
BEGIN
    insert into @gaps
    select distinct
        e1.end_date,
        e2.start_date
    from
        EVENTS e1
        join EVENTS e2
        on e1.end_date < e2.start_date
        and e1.person_id = @v_person_id
        and e2.start_date =
            (select 
                MIN(start_date)
            from
                EVENTS e3
            where
                e3.start_date > e1.end_date
                and person_id = @v_person_id)
        and not exists
            (select
                *
            from
                EVENTS e
            where
                e.start_date < e1.end_date
                and e.end_date > e1.end_date
                and e.person_id = @v_person_id)
    RETURN 
END
```

And just used the *DATEDIFF* function to calculate the duration between the two dates.

```
select distinct
    person_id,
    gaps.end_date,
    gaps.start_date,
    datediff(day,gaps.end_date,gaps.start_date) as duration
from
    EVENTS evnt
    cross apply fun_tbl_find_gaps_in_referrals(evnt.person_id) gaps
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/da289/2).